Web scraping with puppeteer - hidden element
I am scraping a website, and I can't seem to automate the pressing of a 'button' that has 'Create Order' on it, even though it is perfectly clickable manually. Here is the HTML element:
<a id="lb_new_order" class="btn btn-success lb_new_order" href="javascript:__doPostBack('lb_new_order','')">Create Order</a>

However, I'm not sure why, but this is only findable AFTER I have keyword searched for 'Create Order' in 'Elements', or after expanding elements myself and finding it in the HTML code - this seems to be the only thing that makes it findable (not even manually clicking on the button makes it findable with a search).
I have been using this in the Chrome console to see if I can access the element:

[...document.querySelectorAll('a')]

.filter(element =>

element.innerText.includes('Create Order')

)

And as I said before, it returns nothing no matter what until I find it in the HTML code myself, and then after that, it instantly works and returns this:
[a#lb_new_order.btn.btn-success.lb_new_order]

I have tried interacting with the page in many ways to see if it is findable, but this doesn't seem to be working.
Could anyone help with this?

Please share the site and your code as a [mcve]. There's no way to help otherwise.

@ggorlen, thank you very much for your comment - I will admit, it was a bit of a longshot as I'm afraid I'm not sure I can share any information on the site. Fortunately I have found a solution - the element was inside an iframe, and I got it to work by iterating through the frames until I found the one containing the desired element, and then interacting with it that way. Thank you, and have a great day:)

Good to hear, although the purpose of the site is to curate a resource for future visitors with the same problem with you, so a reprex and a self answer with complete code in both would be good.

I posted a similar version of the question on r/webscraping and a user commented that the issue may be caused by the element being in a seperate context/iframe. To test this, I decided to iterate through all of the frames on the web page, and check each of them for the element one at a time, and only interacting with the frame containing the desired element. This worked! Here is my code:
page.on("dialog", async (dialog) => {
        console.log("Dialog message:", dialog.message())
        await dialog.accept()
        console.log("Dialog accepted")
    })

    // Iterates through frames, searching for the one containing the element. Then interacts with that element
    const frames = page.frames()
    let frameWithElement = null
    for (const frame of frames) {
        const elementHandle = await frame.$("#lb_new_order")
        if (elementHandle) {
            frameWithElement = frame
            break
        }
    }

    if (frameWithElement) {
        await frameWithElement.evaluate(() => {
            const newOrderButton = document.querySelector("#lb_new_order")
            if (newOrderButton) {
                const clickEvent = new MouseEvent("click", {
                    view: window,
                    bubbles: true,
                    cancelable: true,
                })
                newOrderButton.dispatchEvent(clickEvent)
            } else {
                console.error("Element with id lb_new_order not found.")
            }
        })
        console.log("Clicked the element with id lb_new_order.")
    } else {
        console.error("Frame with element lb_new_order not found.")
        await browser.close()
        return c.text("Frame with element lb_new_order not found", 400)
    }

